# update or if not exist create file Google Drive .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, google-drive-api

I have a zip file and I managed to upload it but I recreate the zip each time I upload. I wanted to know if there is a way to update the previous zip on google drive with the new zip i created. Or do i need to delete the old one and upload the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can update it. You will need to know the File ID, which you can get from the `create` response, or by searching for the file with `files.find`.

Once you have the File ID, you can send an `update` to it.

All of these operations are explained very well in the docs at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#methods